# Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature key was not found" using auth0

Tags: c#, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, bearer-token, minimal-apis

I am having an issue with authenticating my webapi(.net core 7 minimal api) requests:I can successfully generate a token but when I pass it over to another endpoint that requires authentication I get the error:

> Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature key was not found"

This is my auth token generation method:

```
public class JWTProvider : IJWTProvider
{
    private readonly JwtOptions _options;
    private readonly IPermissionService _permissionService;
    private SecurityToken token;

    public JWTProvider(IOptions<JwtOptions> options, IPermissionService permissionService)
    {
        _options = options.Value;
        _permissionService = permissionService;
    }

    public async Task<string> Generate(UserInformation user)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserID.ToString()),
            new(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, user.userEmail),
            new("userId", user.UserID.ToString()),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
        };

        var permissions = new HashSet<string>()
            { "Admin", "User", "Manager" }; // await _permissionService.GetPermissionsAsync((int)user.UserID);
        claims.AddRange(permissions.Select(permission => new Claim("permissions", permission.ToString())));

        var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
            new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_options.SecretKey)), 
            SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_options.Issuer, _options.Audience,
            claims, DateTime.UtcNow, DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30), signingCredentials);

        string tokenValue = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);

        return await Task.FromResult(tokenValue);
    }
```

and below it is how I verify the token:

```
public class JWTBearerOptionsSetup : IConfigureOptions<JwtBearerOptions>
{
private readonly JwtOptions _jwtOptions;

public JWTBearerOptionsSetup(IOptions<JwtOptions> jwtOptions)
{
    _jwtOptions = jwtOptions.Value;
}
public void Configure(JwtBearerOptions options)
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new()
    {
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = _jwtOptions.Audience,
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = _jwtOptions.Issuer,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        RequireSignedTokens = false,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_jwtOptions.SecretKey)),
    };
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
    {
        OnMessageReceived = ValidateToken
    };
}
}
```

In my program.cs I have the following code:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
options.DefaultSignInScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(auth =>
 {
   auth.AddPolicy("Bearer", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().AddAuthenticationSchemes( JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());
});
builder.Services.ConfigureOptions<JWTOptionsSetup>();
builder.Services.ConfigureOptions<JWTBearerOptionsSetup>();
```

I have added logs and I can see this error in the logs:

```
 Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException: IDX10500: Signature validation failed. No security keys were provided to validate the signature.
     at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateSignature(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, BaseConfiguration configuration)
     at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateJWS(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, BaseConfiguration currentConfiguration, SecurityToken& signatureValidatedToken, ExceptionDispatchInfo& exceptionThrown)
  --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
     at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(String token, JwtSecurityToken outerToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken& signatureValidatedToken)
     at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken& validatedToken)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
```

Does anyone see anything I have missed?

Comment: i guess it tries to locate the signing key, with the matching kid (claim) in the access token, but can't find it? can you add a sample access token to the question? I also did blog about debugging jwt problems here :https://nestenius.se/2023/02/21/troubleshooting-jwtbearer-authentication-problems-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: this is one of the jwt produced: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxNCIsImVtYWlsIjoiY29saXZlckB5aGFvby5jb20iLCJ1c2VySWQiOiIxNCIsImp0aSI6IjE4OWQ3YzhjLWNiNDktNDQ2Ny1hZDA1LTk4YTZkY2U3NzU1NSIsInBlcm1pc3Npb25zIjpbIkFkbWluIiwiVXNlciIsIk1hbmFnZXIiXSwibmJmIjoxNjg0MTQwNTM3LCJleHAiOjE2ODQxNDIzMzcsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vZGV2LWJmYnBlNXplbHVvcnBybXMudXMuYXV0aDAuY29tLyIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjQ0NTU1L2FwaS9hdXRoIn0.02vOMqaG74ewgDgmP1k1ECD4yqcS17R9_qUZ5ef-94g

Comment: try to set .AddJwtBearer(cfg => { cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;....)

Comment: Also, how long is your secret, should be >16 chars.

Comment: The key is an autogenerated from auth0.

Comment: do you have any update on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you had is `No security keys were provided to validate the signature.` this makes me think if it's related to the `TokenValidationParameters` we configured in Program.cs.

I had code like below

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(securityService.Key);
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ThisismySecretKey")),
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
        };
    });
```

When I comment `IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ThisismySecretKey"))` then I used the token I generated via key `ThisismySecretKey`, I got error like below:

[image]

If I have that line of code, my token worked for me.

Comment: I have accepted your response, this one is one of my bad replacing the 
builder.Services.ConfigureOptions<JWTBearerOptionsSetup>(); by using the code inside fixed the issue: basically doing .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(securityService.Key);
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {

Comment: thank you for your kind response and I'm glad to see your issue is solved : )